# Arch Linux GPU benchmark low score

Tags: linux, drivers, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu

I have Asus N550JK laptop with Manjaro Linux installed. The CPU is i7 4700HQ, the dedicated GPU is Geforce GTX850m. It seems that there is a gpu driver problem in my laptop, because the score of integrated graphics in glmark2 is higher than the score of nvidia gpu. This is the information that glmark2 provides about external gpu when I run it using DLI_PRIME=1:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2017.07
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     nouveau
    GL_RENDERER:   NV117
    GL_VERSION:    3.1 Mesa 18.2.3
```

And the score of this benchmark is only 700 points. I tried to switch to proprietary nvidia driver, but during loading I got only black screen. What is the problem of low perfomance of the gpu?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem of low performance of the gpu?

The problem is the inadequacy of the open-source graphics driver you're using, `nouveau`.

Nvidia proprietary drivers are required for optimal performance.

Comment: I know you had problems with the Nvidia drivers but that was not the question. If you need help with that please ask a different and specific question. But before you do that I recommend you browse the excellent and helpful Arch Wiki and forum.